# Convert PDF to text: Adobe Reader vs. Python libraries

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer, adobe-reader

I have a PDF which I try to convert to text for further processing.

The structure of the PDF is stable but tricky, as it also contains elements and graph that sometimes also serve as a background for the text that is written in the particular position. Therefore, I'd like to extract as much text as possible.

I first tried the Adobe Reader function to save the PDF as text which gives good results but doesn't allow to have this process fully automated. At least I don't know a way to interact with the Adobe Reader through the command line or.

Therefore, I tried some python libraries designed for this purpose but it seems that they have a different way to convert the pdf to text. I tried PdfMiner, PyPDF2 and pdftotext. None of the libraries give me the same result as the Adobe Reader.

The PDF looks like the following (a little cropped due to sensitive data which isn't relevant):

[image]

Adobe extracts the following text:

> OCT  15°  (4.3  mm)  ART  (25)  Q:  34  [HR]
>
> ILMILM200μm200μm 04590135180225270315360
>
> TMPTSNSNASNITITMP
>
> 1000  800  600  400  200  0
>
> Position  [°]
>
> CC
> 7.7  (APS)
>
> G227(12%) T206(54%) TS226(20%) TI304(38%) N203(5%) NS213(6%)
> NI276(12%) Segmentationunconfirmed! Classification  MRW  Within
> Normal  Limits
>
> OCT  ART  (100)  Q:  31  [HS]
>
> ILMILMRNFLRNFL200μm200μm 111 04590135180225270315360
>
> 300  240  180  120  60  0
>
> TMP  TS  NS  NAS  NI  TI  TMP
>
> Position  [°]
>
> CC
> 7.7  (APS)
>
> Classification  RNFLT  Outside  Normal  Limits
>
> G78<1% T62(15%) TS103(5%) TI134(10%) N65(7%) NS77(3%) NI73(3%)
> Segmentationunconfirmed! RNFL  Thickness  (3.5  mm)  [μm]
>
> WithinNormalLimits(>5%) Borderline(<5%)OutsideNormalLimits(<1%)

While, for example, PDFminer extracts:

> Average Thickness [�m]
>
> Vol [mm�]
> 8.26
>
> 200 �m 200 �m
>
> OCT 20.0� (5.6 mm) ART (21) Q: 25 [HS]
>
> 267
> 1.42
>
> 321
> 0.50
>
> 335
> 0.53
>
> 299
> 1.59
>
> Center:
>
> Central Min:
>
> Central Max:
>
> 222 �m
>
> 221 �m
>
> 314 �m
>
> Circle Diameters:  1, 3, 6 mm ETDRS
>
> 292
> 1.55
>
> 331
> 0.52
>
> 272
> 0.21
>
> 326
> 0.51
>
> 271
> 1.44
>
> ILMILM
>
> BMBM
>
> 200 �m 200 �m

Which is a lot different. Is there any reason for that and do you know any python library that has the same ability of the Adobe Reader to convert PDF to text?

Comment: First of all, without the PDF in question we obviously cannot tell exactly, merely guess. A common cause for differences is that Adobe Reader also inspects **ActualText** tags which automatic text extractors usually don't (I don't know whether the known Python libraries would optionally support that). As said above, though, this might or might not be the cause in case of your document.

Comment: I have an anonymized pdf example right now that I can share. What would be the best way to make it available to you?

Comment: Adobe Reader will infer reading order based on the page layout when extracting text. The other tools you mention extract the text in the order that the text is painted on the page (display list order). This means that the text order will be influenced by how the PDF file was authored when using those tools.

Comment: @joelgeraci thanks for the clarification. But this doesn't explain why the extracted text differ, does it?

Comment: *"I have an anonymized pdf example right now that I can share. What would be the best way to make it available to you?"* - If you're still interested in an analysis, you can share the file, e.g. as a public google drive or dropbox share, and add the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily an explanation as to why Adobe Reader extracts the text from a pdf differently as opposed to some python libraries but I have achieved a really good solution with [tika](https://pypi.org/project/tika/).

This is was tika extracted:

> OCT 15� (4.2 mm) ART (26) Q: 31 [HR]
>
> NITSTMP NAS TMPTINSM in
>
> im u
>
> m  R
>
> im  W
>
> id th
>
> [ �
>
> m ]
>
> 1000 800 600 400 200
>
> 0
>
> Position [�]
>
> 36031527022518013590450
>
> ILMILM
>
> RNFLRNFL
>
> 200 �m200 �m
>
> OCT ART (100) Q: 27 [HS]
>
> NITSTMP NAS TMPTINS
>
> R N
>
> F L  T
>
> h ickn
>
> e ss (3
>
> .5  m
>
> m ) [�
>
> m ]
>
> 300 240 180 120 60 0
>
> Position [�]
>
> 36031527022518013590450
>
> 40
>
> G 240
>
> (10%)
>
> T 239
>
> (70%)
>
> TS 213 (9%)
>
> TI 285
>
> (22%)
>
> N 230 (5%)
>
> NS 209 (3%)
>
> NI 283 (9%)
>
> CC 7.7 (APS)
>
> Segmentation unconfirmed!
>
> Classification MRW
>
> Borderline
>
> G 78
>
> <1%
>
> T 58
>
> (8%)
>
> TS 91
>
> (2%)
>
> TI 124 (6%)
>
> N 64
>
> (8%)
>
> NS 110
>
> (43%)
>
> NI 71
>
> (4%)
>
> CC 7.7 (APS)
>
> Segmentation unconfirmed!
>
> Classification RNFLT
>
> Outside Normal Limits
>
> Within Normal  Limits (>5%)
>
> Borderline (<5%) Outside Normal  Limits (<1%)
>
> Reference database: European Descent (2014)